# My local Javascript file (for a test website) isn't working in ANY BROWSER...I have tried everything

Tags: javascript, browser

I have checked the code millions of times, and I know the code works because it's working perfectly in Codepen. It's working on friends' laptops too. I have disabled any restrictions (using the allow-local-files thingy on Chrome), and made sure the path is correct et. How can I resolve this?

Is there any other way I can view my local Javascript file (not Codepen)?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Construtive &amp; Co.</title>
</head>
<body><h1>Constructive &amp; Co.</h1>
<p>For all orders and inquiries please call <em>555-3344</em></p>
<script src="js/add-content.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the JS:

```
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;

if (hourNow > 18) {
greeting = 'Good evening!';
} else if (hourNow > 12) {
greeting = 'Good afternoon!';
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
greeting = 'Good morning!';
} else {
greeting = 'Welcome!'
}

document.write('<h3>' + greeting + '</h3>');
```

Comment: If you don't post the code here, we can't help you

Comment: You never explained what isn't work. You just say "isn't working" and that's it. This is in no way a sufficient problem description about a specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this just before closing head tag `"</head>"`

```
<script src="js/add-content.js"></script>
```